# Check if Radio Button is clicked (Selected) - Smarty Template

Tags: php, smarty

I have to implement a solution in PHP/OXID in this way:
To have radio button during the checkout, and if the radio button is selected, variable $customerAnswer to be assigned with 'Ja'. If not, with 'Nein'. So, I know how to implement this by submitting the form, but the variables should be assigned to the controller without reloading the page.

I have defined radio button in smarty template:

```
<input type="radio" name="AcceptTerms" value="Ja/Nein"/>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with using AJAX that sends radio button value to the controller when it’s clicked without reloading the page.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

`<input type="radio" name="AcceptTerms" value="Ja"/>`

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['AcceptTerms']))
      $Terms = "Ja";
else
      $Terms = "Nein";
```

Comment: But is there any possibility to do check in the smarty template?